# Is it true that $\int_y\int_x|\delta(x=y)f(y)|^2\,dydx=\int_y|f(y)|^2\,dy$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I want to prove or disprove $$\int_y\int_x|\delta(x=y)f(y)|^2\,dydx=\int_y|f(y)|^2\,dy.$$

One "proof" is $$\int_y\int_x|\delta(x=y)f(y)|^2\,dydx=\int_y\int_x\delta(x=y)g(x)\,dxdy=\int_yg(y)\,dy=\int_y\delta(y=y)|f(y)|^2\,dy=\int_y|f(y)|^2\,dy$$where $g(x)=\delta(x=y)|f(x)|^2$.

I am unsure about the last step.

Comment: Two comments: $\delta^2$ of the same argument is never defined and $\delta(x=y)$ would not be the properly assigned notation for any context. Usually this would be written instead as $\delta(x-y)$ if you are going to be writing out the integral signs since using rigorous distribution theory does not write out integrals for deltas. But your "steps" after the first one are valid (so long as the domain of integration contain the line $y=x$) since $f(x)\delta(x-a) = f(a)\delta(x-a)$ is a well-known delta mass property. It is just the first step which is not valid.

Comment: The first inequality is simply a rewriting I do not see how it is not valid. Is it because the g I have defined is not a function?

Comment: Like I said any expression with $\delta^2(f)$ is undefined/invalid unless it's $\delta(f)\delta(g)$ of distinct expressions in the arguments.

Comment: You cannot use iterated integration via Fubini's theorem because $\delta^2$ is not integrable.